# Play - Upload file without saving to temp folder

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a following snippet in my Play 2.3 Controller:

```
     def uploadFile = SecuredAction(false, Some(WithProducerRole), parse.multipartFormData) {
    request =>
      val result = Future {
        request.body.files.map {
          uploadedFile =>
            //... processing file
     }
```

This `parse.multipartFormData`  body parser by default creates multipartBody* file under my local Temp folder. It is possible to delete it afterwards but my goal is to prevent it from creation. Any suggestion how to do it? Or some other parser?

Comment: Have a look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11916911/play-2-x-reactive-file-upload-with-iteratees

Comment: You need to create your own body parser.