# Uploading file as stream in play framework 2.0

Tags: java, upload, stream, playframework-2.0

I'm writing a play 2.0 java application that allows users to upload files. Those files are stored on a third-party service I access using a Java library, the method I use in this API has the following signature:

```
void store(InputStream stream, String path, String contentType)
```

I've managed to make uploads working using the following simple controller:

```
public static Result uploadFile(String path) {
    MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
    FilePart filePart = body.getFile("files[]");
    InputStream is    = new FileInputStream(filePart.getFile())
    myApi.store(is,path,filePart.getContentType()); 
    return ok();
  }
```

My concern is that this solution is not efficient because by default the play framework stores all the data uploaded by the client in a temporary file on the server then calls my uploadFile() method in the controller.

In a traditional servlet application I would have written a servlet behaving this way:

```
myApi.store(request.getInputStream(), ...)
```

I have been searching everywhere and didn't find any solution. The closest example I found is [Why makes calling error or done in a BodyParser's Iteratee the request hang in Play Framework 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11468768/why-makes-calling-error-or-done-in-a-bodyparsers-iteratee-the-request-hang-in-p) but I didn't found how to modify it to fit my needs.

Is there a way in play2 to achieve this behavior, i.e. having the data uploaded by the client to go "through" the web-application directly to another system ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've been able to stream data to my third-party API using the following Scala controller code:

```
def uploadFile() = 
    Action( parse.multipartFormData(myPartHandler) ) 
    {
      request => Ok("Done")
    }

def myPartHandler: BodyParsers.parse.Multipart.PartHandler[MultipartFormData.FilePart[Result]] = {
        parse.Multipart.handleFilePart {
          case parse.Multipart.FileInfo(partName, filename, contentType) =>
            //Still dirty: the path of the file is in the partName...
            String path = partName;

            //Set up the PipedOutputStream here, give the input stream to a worker thread
            val pos:PipedOutputStream = new PipedOutputStream();
            val pis:PipedInputStream  = new PipedInputStream(pos);
            val worker:UploadFileWorker = new UploadFileWorker(path,pis);
            worker.contentType = contentType.get;
            worker.start();

            //Read content to the POS
            Iteratee.fold[Array[Byte], PipedOutputStream](pos) { (os, data) =>
              os.write(data)
              os
            }.mapDone { os =>
              os.close()
              Ok("upload done")
            }
        }
   }
```

The UploadFileWorker is a really simple Java class that contains the call to the thrid-party API.

```
public class UploadFileWorker extends Thread {
String path;
PipedInputStream pis;

public String contentType = "";

public UploadFileWorker(String path, PipedInputStream pis) {
    super();
    this.path = path;
    this.pis = pis;
}

public void run() {
    try {
        myApi.store(pis, path, contentType);
        pis.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        try {pis.close();} catch (Exception ex2) {}
    }
}
```

}

It's not completely perfect because I would have preferred to recover the path as a parameter to the Action but I haven't been able to do so. I thus have added a piece of javascript that updates the name of the input field (and thus the partName) and it does the trick.

Comment: Is there anyway to do this in Java instead of Scala? :(