# Accessing session information inside a custom PartHandler in Play! Framework 2.0

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

In order to achieve a streaming upload I have written a custom PartHandler ([Thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066993/uploading-file-as-stream-in-play-framework-2-0) ).

I now need to access a value that is stored inside the play! session inside the PartHandler.
How can I do that ?

Code sample:

```
 def uploadFile() = 

    Action( parse.multipartFormData(myPartHandler) ) 
      {  request => 
           request.session.get("myValue") // <-- Recovering value is fine here
           Ok("Done") }

    def myPartHandler: BodyParsers.parse.Multipart.PartHandler[MultipartFormData.FilePart[Result]] = {
      parse.Multipart.handleFilePart {

        case parse.Multipart.FileInfo(partName, filename, contentType) =>

         // ** Need to access a value in session here **
         //request.session.get("myValue")...

        // Handle part ...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of [other users of the play! framework google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!starred/play-framework/vKGOgzb-FbE), here is how to access the request inside a custom partHandler.

```
//Create a body parser
val myBodyParser = BodyParser { request => 
    parse.multipartFormData(myPartHandler(request)).apply(request)
}

 def uploadFile() = Action(myBodyParser) 
      {request =>Ok("Done")}

 def myPartHandler(request: RequestHeader) : BodyParsers.parse.Multipart.PartHandler[MultipartFormData.FilePart[Result]] = {
    parse.Multipart.handleFilePart {
      case parse.Multipart.FileInfo(partName, filename, contentType) =>         
        println(request.session.get("myValueKey"));
```